# Win 10 and proxy pac

Tags: proxy, windows-10, pac

I've just installed the win 10 developer preview and I've tried to set up the proxy configuration with a pac file on an http:blabla url.

I can surf the net but not totally, for example I can use Skype and access Gmail but I cannot see Gmail icons or some other Web sites css/images.

In some web sites I get appliance error(configuration error) your request could not be processed because of a configuration error : username could not be converted to kerberos name.

On stack overflow I've seen some one suggest to use rsat but after I've install it I cannot see the server manager voice on the control panel section.

P. S. Browser doesn't ask me for proxy authentication

Andrea.

Answer (score 0):

So, proxifier is a not free software that force all your programs to use a specified proxy address. 
It's cool except that it's not free... 30 days of trial, till we wait the window patches!